# How to bind key to another key in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, binding, keyboard-shortcuts, key

I would like to map my "WASD" to the arrows.

I don't like moving my hands around. I already fixed it for my editor by calling W for arrowUp.

But, how can I bind it for the entire system?
When I call W, I want it to call the arrow UP.

I can't bind those keys one software at the time.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

-hbt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To determine the keycodes for keys on
>   your keyboard, you can run a program
>   called "xev". When running, you just
>   press keys and you'll see the codes
>   appear in the program. By keeping
>   track of these you can make changes to
>   the keys that need updating.
>
> Then, you use a commandline program
>   called "xmodmap
>   (http://cf.ccmr.cornell.edu/cgi-bin/w3mman2html.cgi?xmodmap(1))"
>   to remap a keystroke. So for instance:
>
> ```
>  xmodmap -e 'keycode 234=F2'
> ```
>
> This would remap the key on the
>   keyboard that generates keycode signal
>   234 to now be treated as the "F2" key.
>   You can read the xmodmap documentation
>   online to determine how to refer to
>   various keystrokes.
>
> So then you can build up a list of
>   xmodmap lines, and put them all in a
>   script that gets executed at login
>   time, so that your keyboard is mapped
>   the way you like.

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-354969.html